# How to read data from external BT dongle in core-java?

Tags: java, bluetooth

I am trying to read the data from external bluetooth dongle connected to my machine as soon as it receives the data from any other bluetooth device in java.I do not know how to achieve this.If any one knows how to do this please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the solution for my own question.We can achieve this using "bluecove apis".The following links are very useful.

[Bluecove_Link1](http://raquibulbari.wordpress.com/category/bluecove/)

[Bluecove](http://code.google.com/p/bluecove/)

[Bluecove_API_Reference](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/bluecove/bluecove/2.1.0/bluecove-2.1.0-javadoc.jar!/index.html)